# Is there a verb for the act of someone paying you to take something away?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you give someone money for a particular good or service, you are buying that thing. But do we have a word for a scenario where someone says:

> My old couch is just taking up space, I'll give you $20 to haul it away.

What do we call what the person who profits in this scenario is doing?

Comment: Hauling is a service for which you pay. The person you pay is a hauler.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a single word, but you could say

> My old couch is just taking up space, I'll give you $20 to **dispose of** it.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dispose-of?q=dispose+of+something) has

> **dispose of something**
> to get rid of something; throw out or destroy:

Answer (score 1):

***Clearance***

> the process of removing waste or things you do not want from a place ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clearance))

Such services are commonly referred to as *[house clearance services](https://www.google.com/search?q=clearance%20services&ei=v35iY7vEFpL5gQa84IsI&ved=0ahUKEwj7n47U2o_7AhWSfMAKHTzwAgEQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=clearance%20services&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIICAAQgAQQiwMyCAgAEIAEEIsDMgsIABCABBDJAxCLAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6DQgAEEcQ1gQQsAMQyQM6CAgAEIAEEMkDSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUNoFWIMKYKUNaAFwAXgAgAFeiAH1AZIBATOYAQCgAQHIAQi4AQPAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)*.

---

**Edit**: It is true that this is used in BE, which is the language I am most exposed to. But you do say "$20", so you are probably looking for an AE variant.

I can see expressions such as *Junk/Furniture Removal* being used in American ads.

> Junk King is an eco-friendly ***junk removal** company* headquartered in South San Francisco, CA. ([Source](https://www.junk-king.com/))

You will notice in the subtitle of the page the verb you used yourself, *hauling*.

This site explains it well:

> Whether you are ***decluttering***, ***relocating***, ***redecorating***, or ***renovating***, you would probably benefit greatly from ***junk removal***. But if you’re not already familiar with ***junk removal services***, you might be wondering how exactly they work and what to expect.([loadup](https://goloadup.com/what-is-junk-removal/))

Comment: Not in American English.

Answer (score 0):

"**Decluttering**" and "**disposing of**" had been mentioned. You can call the money paid "**decluttering charges**" and "**disposal charges**", the services as "**decluttering service**" and "**disposal service**".

> **Jettisoning** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jettisoning#English)) The action by which something is jettisoned. **Jettison**: To let go or get rid of as being useless or
> defective.
>
> - You can call the money paid "**jettisoning charges**" and the person "**jettisoning facilitator**".

**Good riddance** ([FARLEX](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+riddance)) said to express relief at having got free of a troublesome or unwanted person or thing. "**Good riddance payoff**" and "**consignee**"